# Javascript function is not executed each time when called

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which is called from another function I have.

For some reasons, this function is not executed each time when called. I have tryed to change the name of the function, and then everything works fine.

I don't understand why. Here is a litle example:

```
javascript 1:

function a()
{ 
   b();
}

javascript 2:

function b()
{ 
   c();
}

javascript 3:

function c()
{ 
   alert("Function c");
}
```

The function c is not executed for some reasons... If for example the function c will be called newC(), then it works fine.

Comment: Are these three different compilation blocks (e.g. files)?  What are you **actually executing**; these are just definitions of functions, how do they get called?

Comment: Could you please provide a [running example](http://sscce.org) with proper comments? There is no call to `a` in your current example.

Comment: Thank you for your ansewer @AndrzejDoyle. Function a() is in separate js file and function b() and c() are in the same js file. I am actually executing the first javascript file with the function a(), then that function will call the function b from the second js file and the function b() will call the function c() from the same file.

Comment: @Zeta, thank you for the answer. The function a() is called when a button iz clicked. The function b is executed properly but not the c.

Comment: you said you changed the function names and it worked fine, so please post the original code you wrote with the non-working name. Probably that name was already used by other function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a conflict of names in the scope of `b()` i.e. when `b()` is executed, it can happen that `c` is defined to something else in a current scope.

Solution: Start your JavaScript debugger, set a breakpoint in `b()` and check what `c` is at that time.

Comment: Oh, you're right @Aaron, I have run the debuger and I defined another function with the same name in the js file b, so there was a name conflict. Stupid error from my side. Sorry and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works fine. May be you have some error in the code. IF u post the full code i may able to help. here is the working code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function a()
{
b();
}
function b()
{
c();
}
function c()
{
alert("hello");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>Hello</label>
<button onclick="a()">v</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution, I defined the function c twice, so there were name conflicts.